# badblocks source code

Tags: badblocks

I don't know English but analyzing is little possible.

I need the source code badblocks.
I hope header file for that too.(ex)com_err.h)
I wish to recommend programs tools, too.

Answer (score 6):

`badblocks` is part of `e2fsprogs`, whose source code lives in [this git repository](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git). Specifically, you'll find [`badblocks.c`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/badblocks.c) in the `misc` folder. `comm_err.h` is in [`lib/et`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/et).